# ssh-agent not getting set up (SSH_AUTH_SOCK, SSH_AGENT_PID env vars not set)

Tags: bash, ssh, kubuntu, ssh-agent

I set up a new user account for a friend on Kubuntu 12.04. When he uses `ssh` he gets this error:

> Could not open a connection to your authentication agent

We're running `ssh` in some bash scripts.

After looking around at the wide variety of things that can lead to that error, I came across this solution:

```
$ eval `ssh-agent -s`
$ ssh-add ~/.ssh/some_id_rsa
```

Then he can run the `ssh` commands (and bash scripts) as expected.

Before running those two commands, the env variables are not set in a terminal:

```
$ echo $SSH_AGENT_PID

$ echo $SSH_AUTH_SOCK

$
```

After running the commands, the env variables are set as expected. However, they do not stay set (e.g., in a different shell or after rebooting).

I want to know how to set up his computer so he doesn't have to run those two commands to set the env variables. I do not need to run them on my computer (ever). So far I am not seeing what is different between our machines.

I see this info in the man page, but it does not tell me how Ubuntu is normally setting up the agent automatically or what is happening on my friend's machine so that this is not working for him.

> There are two main ways to get an agent set up: The first is that the
>        agent starts a new subcommand into which some environment variables are
>        exported, eg ssh-agent xterm &.  The second is that the agent prints the
>        needed shell commands (either sh(1) or csh(1) syntax can be generated)
>        which can be evalled in the calling shell, eg eval `ssh-agent -s` for
>        Bourne-type shells such as sh(1) or ksh(1) and eval `ssh-agent -c` for
>        csh(1) and derivatives.

After installing `acct` and rebooting, this is the output of `lastcomm`:

```
ssh-agent         F    newuser __         0.12 secs Wed Aug  7 11:02
ssh-agent         F    newuser __         0.00 secs Wed Aug  7 20:34
ssh-agent         F    newuser __         0.02 secs Wed Aug  7 20:02
ssh-agent         F    newuser __         0.01 secs Thu Aug  8 12:39
ssh-agent         F    newuser __         0.02 secs Thu Aug  8 07:45
```

From the man page:

> F -- command executed after a fork but without a following exec

I'm not sure if that is significant.

Comment: Under Ubuntu, `ssh-agent` is normally started from `/etc/X11/Xsession.d/90x11-common_ssh-agent`. This can be suppressed by removing `use-ssh-agent` from `/etc/X11/Xsession`. Are those files correct? Is the agent started and then killed or never started? (Install `acct` and run `lastcomm` after logging in to see what programs were lauched.)

Comment: @Gilles-thank you. Those two files are identical on my machine and his machine. We both have `X11/Xsession.options:use-ssh-agent` and `X11/Xsession.d/90x11-common_ssh-agent:SSHAGENT=/usr/bin/ssh-agent`. I will try `acct` and `lastcomm` next. Thanks

Comment: updated question

Comment: still looking for a solution...

Comment: Please post the output of `lastcomm` for a full session, not just the `ssh-agent` process. The point is to see in what order various programs are started.

Comment: I have always used my dot files for this.  I have an alias that starts ssh-agent ( if it's not already running ) and outputs to ~/.ssh_agent.  Whenever a shell starts, my dotfiles will eval it if it's there.

Comment: Does your friend have a .xsession file? That's the main way I can imagine `ssh-agent` not getting run at log in. Other possibilities: try having your friend temporarily log in with a different desktop environment. (There will be a button on the login screen). Also, check the .xsession-errors file to see if there are any relevant errors. I hope that helps!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You mentioned your user is `ssh`ing in, not logging in locally. So the `use-ssh-agent` in `/etc/X11/Xsession.options` is a red herring: it won't be executed on SSH sessions, only when logging into a X11 GUI desktop locally (or using some virtual X11 session like over VNC or RDP).

Instead, you should check if `libpam-ssh` is installed on either system. It can be configured to authenticate a user using SSH private key passphrases, but that is optional and you'll need to specifically place the key to `~/.ssh/login-keys.d/` for that functionality.

Its other feature, though, is to auto-start a SSH agent on any login session and automatically add SSH private keys to the agent if their passphrase is the same as the user's login password. I'm thinking this might be the cause of the different behavior between your systems.

Comment: A fresh install of Ubuntu 22.04 wasn't starting ssh-agent when I logged in over ssh. From past experience with ubuntu, I know it's configured to start ssh-agent. Turns out this new install didn't have `libpam-ssh` installed. Installing that package fixed it: now my login shells have an `ssh-agent` running and get the right `$SSH_ env` vars.

Comment: @dgrogan's solution work for me as well (for ssh login on Ubuntu 23). No need to edit any dot file. Just do "sudo apt install libpam-ssh" and you are done.

Answer (score 11):

For the

```
$ eval `ssh-agent -s`
```

construct to work when put in a “startup script”, your session, and ultimately the terminal where you expect the environment, must be descendants (by `fork` and `exec`) of that script.  The reason is
that the output of `ssh-agent -s`, when evaluated, sets environment
variables **in the shell calling `eval`**.  Form there, they may be handed down, and they may be lost on the way as well.

So if `ssh-agent` is run by script A somewhere during login, but the
terminal B in which you start you shell script is **not a descendant** of
A, then you cannot see the environment in B.

If you happen to have `ssh-agent` started as `systemd --user` service,
then you may have to use convention instead: Don't let `ssh-agent`
specify the variables, but use common knowledge when starting the
agent, and when starting the session.  E.g., my
`~/.config/systemd/user/ssh-agent.service` looks like this:

```
[Unit]
Description=SSH agent

[Service]
Type=simple
Environment=SSH_AUTH_SOCK=%t/ssh-agent.socket
ExecStart=/usr/bin/ssh-agent -D -a $SSH_AUTH_SOCK

[Install]
WantedBy=default.target
```

And in my `~/.profile` I have the line

```
export SSH_AUTH_SOCK="${XDG_RUNTIME_DIR}/ssh-agent.socket"
```

Note that `%t` in the former corresponds to `${XDG_RUNTIME_DIR}` in
the latter.

**Note:** I'm not happy about this!

Comment: Can you please explain the problems of this approach (i.e., why are you not happy about this) and whether or not you've found a better approach in the meantime?

Answer (score 2):

You mentioned that

```
$ eval `ssh-agent -s`
$ ssh-add ~/.ssh/some_id_rsa
```

works as desired. So you just need those to execute at the right time, in .bash_profile or .xsession. Add debug statements like `(date; env|sort) >> /tmp/log` to help you understand exactly when they run.

Answer (score 2):

I found the answer here :

http://www.bernatchez.net/userauth.html

On ubuntu the ssh-add utility fails to load certificate files. It occurs when the agent is the one implemented by gnome-keyring. The fix is to stop using the ssh component of gnome-keyring. Since the initialization process actually starts up a true ssh-agent and then launches gnome-keyring-ssh.desktop which clobbers AUTH_SOCKET to take it over, we can revert back to the original ssh-agent by disabling gnome-keyring-ssh.desktop.

Disable gnome-keyring-ssh.desktop:

```
cd /etc/xdg/autostart/
sudo emacs gnome-keyring-ssh.desktop
```

Add the following line to the desktop file and save it, then reboot:

```
X-GNOME-Autostart-enabled=false
```

Comment: Only that your so-called "true" ssh-agent doesn't access the gnome keyring and therefore still requests the password after every reboot.

Answer (score 1):

### SSH-Keygen for Multi-User Jupyterhub Python Environment:

Trying to setup *SSH-Keygen* in a **multi-user Jupyter Python environment** has proved a major frustration... This of course is obviously preferable to plain text http password for git.

I didn't realize that the `SSH_AUTH_SOCK` wasn't getting carried over to my `ssh-add` after running the `eval ssh-agent` cmd... [@stefan](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/435540/434033) gave a very nice description above which put this all in perspective! More helpful info on ssh-add man page [here](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/ssh-add.1.html) as well...

---

### *You need to run everything in a single bash cmd!*

Below is an example following instructions from GitHub [here](https://docs.github.com/en/github/authenticating-to-github/generating-a-new-ssh-key-and-adding-it-to-the-ssh-agent) on ssh key generation.

- Please notice I use `!` (bang) in the python cell so it runs a bash command in jupyter. More info [here](https://anaconda.zendesk.com/hc/en-us/articles/360023858254-Executing-Terminal-Commands-in-Jupyter-Notebooks#:%7E:text=In%20Jupyter%20Notebook%20you%20can,you%20are%20trying%20to%20use.).
- Also notice the `&& \` to wrap my bash command inside a jupyter python notebook cell so it's *ONE* command:

```py
!ssh-keygen -t ed25519 -C "YOUR_EMAIL@domain.com" -f $HOME/.ssh/id_ed25519 -N "" <<< y && \
eval "$(ssh-agent -s)" && \
ssh-add $HOME/.ssh/id_ed25519
```

#### Confirm your SSH setup

Proceed by adding your SSH key to github. You should then be able to [confirm your github authentication](https://docs.github.com/en/github/authenticating-to-github/checking-for-existing-ssh-keys), this worked for me when running the following:

```py
!ssh -o "StrictHostKeyChecking no" -T user@hostgit@github.com
```

- Please note the flag `-o "StrictHostKeyChecking no"` is *NOT* recommended given there could be a man-in-the-middle attack. I am unsure how to programattically accept this with value *yes*, alternatively you can probably get the known host and manually add to your known host file.

Comment: Just a note about your one-liner, it seems you are specifying ED25519 encryption but then name you key with RSA. Is there a reason?

Comment: No reason other than the fact that most guides online default to RSA and honestly I didn't catch notice. Really though you can name the public and private key whatever you want, probably best to be consistent with recommended extensions here https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/user/ssh.html#see-if-you-have-an-existing-ssh-key-pair (I edited my response to reflect this best practice)